# React-Phone-Input-2 customize border of input on focus

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I would like to change the color of the border of the input on focus, but not sure how to achieve it. I can change the styles the component but not when focusing. I´m using material-ui css option.
Here is the code so far:

```
....
            <PhoneInput
                country={'pt'}
                localization={pt}
                specialLabel={field.label}
                value={phoneValue}
                onChange={phone => setPhoneValue(phone)}
                inputStyle={{
                    '&:focus': {
                        borderColor: 'red'
                    }
                }}
            />
```

Sample:
[image: Edit morning-microservice-871uu]

Thanks!

Comment: `inputStyle` prop accepts plain JS object https://github.com/bl00mber/react-phone-input-2/blob/master/src/index.js#L945 and doesn't know anything about nesting rules.

IMHO, the best solution is to write own CSS for `. react-tel-input. input:focus` selector.

Answer (score 2):

You can change border color by placing a class to containerClass of PhoneInput component. That is, if you you use Material UI you can define a class as following

```
borderClass: {
    "&.react-tel-input .form-control:focus": {
       borderColor: "#69e781",
       boxShadow: "0px 0px 0px 1px #69e781",  
    }
}    

then use this class as follows

<PhoneInput      
  containerClass={classes.borderClass}
  .
  .
/>
```

or if you use a CSS file you can override the rule below in your CSS file

`.react-tel-input .form-control:focus:`

Answer (score 0):

The styles on focusing the input of `React-Phone-Input` exists on `.PhoneInputInput` class on focus-visible property. In order to override this styling, access the `PhoneInputInput` Class.

Below example is for the devs using Material UI styled components.

```js
".PhoneInputInput": {
  "&:focus-visible": {
     outline: "none",
   },
}
```